# I'm trying to determine the Thevenin voltage of a circuit using the node voltage method

Tags: analysis, thevenin

I'm trying to determine the Thevenin voltage between the terminals a and b on this circuit:

[image]

Notice that I've named the three essential nodes \$v_1\$, \$v_2\$ and \$v_3\$. I've highlighted the ground node to the far left. Using the node voltage method, I produced these three equations.

$$v_1: \frac{v_1-600}{10} + \frac{v_1 - v_2}{40} = 0$$
$$v_2: \frac{v_2}{14} + \frac{v_2-v_1}{40} + \frac{v_2 - v_3}{2} = 0$$
$$v_3: \frac{v_3 - v_2}{2} - 12 = 0$$

According to my logic, the Thevenin voltage should equal \$v_1-v_3\$. After solving the system of equations, I got \$270\$V. However, this voltage is not the voltage it's supposed to be, which is \$246\$V. Does anyone know where I got it wrong?

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with your equations, and I'm getting \$v_1 - v_3 = 246\$V with them, so you'll have to show us more of your work to figure out where you went wrong.

Comment: Besides for the sake of exercise, I'd use superimposition to find Vth. You end up with two fairly simple circuits for which you can calculate the partial Vth components with plain series/parallel equivalences and voltage/current divider formulas.

Comment: BTW, the answer *is* 246V. Use LTspice (for example) to simulate the circuit, if you need to check the book/assignment is correct.

Comment: Thank you for all the tips! And yes, I made a banal error. I repeatedly calculated v1-v2 instead of v1-v3.

Comment: Have you tried using mesh current? It seems that it may work to attain the correct voltage? Just times the currents you attain to the 40 and 2 ohm resistor and add it up.